# Stata alternatives for lookup

Tags: stata

I have a large Stata dataset that contains the following variables: `year`, `state`, `household_id`, `individual_id`, `partner_id`, and `race`. Here is an example of my data:

```
 year  state  household_id  individual_id  partner_id  race
 1980  CA     23            2              1           3
 1980  CA     23            1              2           1
 1990  NY     43            4              2           1
 1990  NY     43            2              4           1
```

Note that, in the above table, column 1 and 2 are married to each other.
I want to create a variable that is one if the person is in an interracial marriage.

As a first step, I used the following code

```
by household_id year: gen inter=0 if race==race[partner_id]
replace inter=1 if inter==.
```

This code worked well but gave the wrong result in a few cases. As an alternative, I created a string variable identifying each user and its partner, using

```
 gen id_user=string(household_id)+"."+string(individual_id)+string(year)
 gen id_partner=string(household_id)+"."+string(partner_id)+string(year)
```

What I want to do now is to create something like what `vlookup` does in Excel: for each column, save locally the id_partner, find it in the id_user and find their race, and compare it with the race of the original user.

I guess it should be something like this?

```
gen inter2==1 if (find race[idpartner]) == (race[iduser])
```

The expected output should be like this

```
 year  state  household_id  individual_id  partner_id  race  inter2
 1980  CA     23            2              1           3     1 
 1980  CA     23            1              2           1     1
 1990  NY     43            4              2           1     0
 1990  NY     43            2              4           1     0
```

Comment: Thanks for the data example, but `dataex` goes one step further than you did to give everyone reading the thread code the reproduces the example data in their own Stata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need anything so general. As you realise, the information on identifiers suffices to find couples, and that in turn allows comparison of `race` for the people in each couple.

In the code below `_N == 2` is meant to catch data errors, such as one partner but not the other being an observation in the dataset or repetitions of one partner  or both.

```
clear 

input year  str2 state  household_id  individual_id  partner_id  race
 1980  CA     23            2              1           3
 1980  CA     23            1              2           1
 1990  NY     43            4              2           1
 1990  NY     43            2              4           1 
 end 

generate couple_id = cond(individual_id < partner_id, string(individual_id) + ///
                          " " + string(partner_id), string(partner_id) + ///
                          " " + string(individual_id)) 

bysort state year household_id couple_id : generate mixed = race[1] != race[2] if _N == 2 

list, sepby(household_id) abbreviate(15)

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | year   state   household_id   individual_id   partner_id   race   couple_id   mixed |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 1980      CA             23               2            1      3         1 2       1 |
  2. | 1980      CA             23               1            2      1         1 2       1 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  3. | 1990      NY             43               4            2      1         2 4       0 |
  4. | 1990      NY             43               2            4      1         2 4       0 |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This idea is documented in [this article](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0043). The link gives free access to a `pdf` file.